# Why is msgid_plural necessary in gettext translation files?

Tags: zend-framework, translation, gettext

I've read the [GNU Gettext manual about Translating plural forms](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Translating-plural-forms.html) and see its example:

```
 #, c-format
 msgid "One file removed"
 msgid_plural "%d files removed"
 msgstr[0] "%d slika je uklonjena"
 msgstr[1] "%d datoteke uklonjenih"
 msgstr[2] "%d slika uklonjenih"
```

Why is msgid_plural different from msgid, and doesn't that defeat the purpose of having translations be aware of plural forms?

I'd think that I could do something like this (for English):

```
 #, c-format
 msgid "X geese"
 msgstr[0] "%d goose"
 msgstr[1] "%d geese"

 #, c-format
 msgid "sentence_about_geese_at_the_lake"
 msgstr[0] "There is one goose at the lake."
 msgstr[1] "There are %d geese at the lake."
```

(using just one msgid).

Then in my code, I'd have something like:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('X geese', $numberA); ?> 
<?php echo $this->translate('sentence_about_geese_at_the_lake', $numberB); ?>
```

If $numberA is 3, it would say "3 geese."

If $numberB is 0, the next line would say "There are 0 geese at the lake."

(because for English, the rule is *(n != 1)*, so plural is used for any number that equals 0 or greater than 1).

It seems redundant for me to be required to specify 2 msgids for the same collection of phrases.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the ideas behind gettext is that the `msgid` is extracted from source files to create POT files, which are used as base for translations stored in PO files, and later compiled to MO files. A `msgid` is also used if no suitable translation is found.

A `msgid` is not a "key" that is non-readable by users; it is a real phrase that can be used in the program. So when in your code you request a translation for a plural (pseudocode here):

```
ngettext("One file removed", "%d files removed", file_count)
```

...these two strings will be used a) to extract messages from the source code; these messages will serve as guide for translators b) as the default strings when no suitable translation is found for the current locale.

That's why a plural string has two `msgid`: to show how they are defined in the source program (for translators) and to be used as default (when no translation exists).

In other localization systems, like [Android String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) or [Rails YAML files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), it works like you imagined -- the equivalent to a `msgid` is a single "key" even for plurals, but then the real phrase is not used in the source code, and defining translations is a two-steps action even for the original language.