# Wordpress PHP function _n() only translates singular text

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm in the process of making our Wordpress plugin compatible with translate.wordpress.org and use this code for easy pluralisation/translation:

```
echo _n( 'size', 'sizes', $count, 'my-domain' );
```

We still have .po/.mo files that contain e.g.:

```
msgid "size"
msgstr "afmeting"

msgid "sizes"
msgstr "afmetingen"
```

This is the output I get:

```
echo _n( 'size', 'sizes', 1, 'my-domain' );
// expected: 1 afmeting 
// actual: 1 afmeting 

echo _n( 'size', 'sizes', 2, 'my-domain' );
// expected: 2 afmetingen
// actual: 2 sizes
```

The translations are there, if I reverse the plural/single texts still only the single is translated.

Any thoughts what I'm doing wrong and how I should get it to work?

Comment: everything seems to me fine. What if you put other than 2 ? e.g. 3 ?

Comment: Yields the same result. Perhaps i'm not storing the plural versions of the translations correctly in the .po file. I'll update the trunk soon and see which translatable strings pop up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I was not storing plural translations correctly. I've modified the plugin code to use translate.wordpress.org and the translation is now regarded as one having both a singular and plural version.

The solution for storing it in the .po/.mo files would have been something like this (not tested):

```
msgid "size"
msgid_plural "sizes"
msgstr[0] "afmeting"
msgstr[1] "afmetingen"
```

Also see this: [Why is msgid_plural necessary in gettext translation files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110916/why-is-msgid-plural-necessary-in-gettext-translation-files).